# Android EditText input

Tags: android

Okey, I have EditText where user inputs some  mathematical expression, and I want to calculate  result. It sounds pretty esay at first, but I dont know how to do it in just one EditText?

In regular java, its possible with javax.script, is there any way to do it on Android?

Another issue that is connected to the previous, is that I have 5 TextView where computer put some random numbers, and I want forbid to enter in EditText all other numbers except that 5 numbers that are placed in TextView's.

Comment: i find your questions very ambiguous.  are you having a problem interpreting the math expression, or as you seem to imply to "using just one text box".  if the latter, what is it about using just one textbox that is difficult?

Comment: To be clear and simple, I want to user input some math expression in TextView (  like 10*2, or (10*2)+5 ), and just to calculate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can make your own calculator. postfix calculator would be enough if expression is not that complex. you can find many postfix calculator implementations on the web and here's mine ( http://kingori.egloos.com/2945966 ). Well, it's written in Korean but you can see my source code.
2. second requirement is somewhat complex. you can find numbers from expression by regular expression. so, get numbers first and then compare with 5 nunbers. it's very hard to catch numbers while user types expression.